# call a global function in CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I'm getting a strange behavior with CoffeeScript: the `initMap` function is correctly called from the loaded script (`&callback=initMap`), but I have an error triggered by the last line at `initMap()`

```
# Declare a global function
@initMap = ->
  restaurantLocation =
    lat: $('#restaurant-map').data("lat")
    lng: $('#restaurant-map').data("lng")
  map = new (google.maps.Map) $('#restaurant-map')[0],
    zoom: 19,
    center: restaurantLocation
  marker = new (google.maps.Marker)
    position: restaurantLocation
    map: map

$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  if $('#restaurant-map').length > 0
    if page.included_google_maps_js_api == undefined
      google_maps_api_key = 'xxx'
      # correctly called from here...
      $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + google_maps_api_key + '&callback=initMap')
      page.included_google_maps_js_api = true
    initMap() # Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined
```

What I find funny is that this other snippet is working flawlessly:

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  if $('#restaurant-map').length > 0 && page.included_google_maps_js_api == undefined
    google_maps_api_key = 'xxx'
    $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + google_maps_api_key + '&callback=initMap')
    page.included_google_maps_js_api = true
  else if ($('#restaurant-map').length > 0)
    initMap()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getScript` gets the script **asynchronously**. You're not waiting for the result of that before calling `initMap` in the case where `page.included_google_maps_js_api == undefined` is true.

You just need an `else` (since you're using `&callback=initMap` to call it in the case where need to load):

```
$(document).on 'turbolinks:load', ->
  if $('#restaurant-map').length > 0
    if page.included_google_maps_js_api == undefined
      google_maps_api_key = 'xxx'
      # correctly called from here...
      $.getScript('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=' + google_maps_api_key + '&callback=initMap')
      page.included_google_maps_js_api = true
    else                  # <== Note the else
      initMap()           #     so we only do this if it's loaded
```